# Imposing two conditions on FileUtils listFiles in java

Tags: java, file-handling, fileutils

I want to pick only those files which have "`txt`" extension and are more than 1 minute old. Is there a way to enforce both of these conditions in the `listFiles` method?

To ensure it picks only txt files, this is how I did

```
    Collection<File> myFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.getFile(inputPath),
                                   FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter(".txt"),
                                   null);
```

I could find `isFileOlder()` method in `FileUtils` but how to impose both restrictions to it?

Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [AndFileFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AndFileFilter.html).

This lets you combine any two file filters as a Boolean.  As there isn't a delivered file filter for the age criteria, you'll still need to create one, following the lines of the other comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own [IOFileFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html) , which would do both checks :

```
public class MyFileFilter implements IOFileFilter {

String extension;
Date maxDate;

   public MyFileFilter(String extension, Date maxDate){
    this.extension = extension;
    this.maxDate = maxDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {

    boolean suffixMatches = file.getName().endsWith(extension);
    boolean timeMatches = FileUtils.isFileOlder(file, maxDate);

    return suffixMatches && timeMatches ;
    }
}
```

Then you would call it this way :

```
String extension = ".txt";

// compute current date minus 1 minute
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
Date maxDate = cal.getTime();

Collection<File> myFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.getFile(inputPath),new MyFileFilter(extension,maxDate) ,
            null);
```